# Adding a link on page with current URL (including hash) in a querystring

Tags: javascript, url, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a link to a page. The link should contain the current URL in a querystring (to be used as a `ReturnUrl`) and it can contain a hash.

Middle-clicking, right-clicking and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+clicking should be supported. For example, middle-clicking will open the link in a new tab with (or without) the querystring.

Is this completely off-track, or how can I improve it?

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Links.ThereAndBackAgain())?ReturnUrl=" onclick="this.href += encodeURIComponent(location.href)">
```

Comment: I believe you can skip the JS, and just append the URL in asp.net using the request object http://stackoverflow.com/q/5304782/575527

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Hash should be preserved. Updated the answer  (see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-the-hash-part-of-the-url-is-not-in-the-server-side or this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can possibly be improved.
The location hash may be changed by the client after the page is loaded,
by clicking on local anchors.
This is not visible by the `asp.net`,
and fully visible by the client-side javascript,
in the value of `location.href`.
And since you require the complete URL to be included as part of the query string,
it must be encoded with `encodeURIComponent`,
which you correctly did.